# object won't pack data

Tags: c++, clang, xcode4.3, memory-alignment

I'm trying to pack data in a c++ struct.

My struct has this layout:

```
struct structName
{
  int16_t member1;
  int32_t member2;
  uint32_t member3;
  uint32_t member4;
  uint32_t member5;
  etc
}__attribute__((packed));
```

Using `offsetof($structname, $membername)` I get back the correct offsets of the data (0,2,6,10,14 . . .), but when I access the data by member-name I get the data at 4 byte offsets (0,4,8,12,16 . . .) as if the struct wasn't packed.

Is

```
} __attribute__((packed));
```

the correct way to make a struct packed?
    .
    .

Comment: You might consider posting the actual code to the data structure

Comment: @ChetSimpson you want me to wrap it with `struct $structname {  ... }__attribute__((packed));` and add the member names?

Comment: Looks like an alignment issue

Comment: @ShaggyFrog It is an alignment issue.  The question is why `offsetof` indicates different offsets than those used by the members;

Comment: Might actually be a clang/llvm bug. Can you post the code you're using to verify the offsets of data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update: *mydogisbox* wrote:

> For the record, `__attribute__((packed))`, `#pramga pack(1)` and `#pragma pack(push, 1)` all worked.

`__attribute__((packed))` is a **gcc** extension, which is supported.

The clang documentation says it also supports `#pragma pack(...)` directive:

> clang has some experimental support for extensions from Microsoft
>   Visual C++; to enable it, use the -fms-extensions command-line option.
>   This is the default for Windows targets. Note that the support is
>   incomplete; enabling Microsoft extensions will silently drop certain
>   constructs (including __declspec and Microsoft-style asm statements).
>
> clang supports the Microsoft `#pragma pack` feature for controlling record layout.

source: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html

Just say:

```
#pragma pack(1)
struct my_struct {
    int16_t x;
    // etc.
};
```

to see if it works (compile with `-fms-extensions` if not using Windows).

Note the above are all non-standard extensions, and the new C++11 standard has a new `alignas` keyword: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas

```
struct alignas(1) my_struct {
    int16_t x;
    // etc.
};
```

but its support is still a bit sketchy.

Comment: I get the same result for `#pragma pack(1)` and `#pragma pack(push, 1)`

Comment: added some more possibly relevant info. if that doesn't fix it, I guess it could be a bug in clang.

Comment: which solution did you use? pragma pack or alignas?

Comment: It turns out I had a problem with my code that made it look like it wasn't working.  For the record, `__attribute__((packed))`, `#pramga pack(1)` and `#pragma pack(push, 1)` all worked.

Comment: Does `alignas(1)` on a struct actually function the same as packing, or does it just set a *mininmum* alignment, which the compiler takes the max of along with the natural alignment of each field?

Comment: @dwayne-robinson  I think you might be right: *cppreference.com* says *the declared entity will have its alignment requirement set to exactly the result of the expression, **except if it would weaken the natural alignment requirement of the type**.* So it would seem **alignas(1)** is not the same as packing.